# Golang - Unit test for parse yaml file and check objects

Tags: go, yaml

I want to test parse of yaml and test it via unit test
I’ve create structs that with appropriate types but the assertion is always 
falid, I try with the following code which failed constantly

This is the yaml content which is **valid**  (maybe with the copy it changed but I was able to parse it correctly)

```
ID: demo
version: 0.0.5

dep:
 - name: db
   path: mtb
   requires:
    - name: vi_db


 - name: srv
   path: srv1
   properties:
     LOG_LEVEL: "info"


   parameters:
     mem: 12G
   requires:
     - name: db
       properties:
```

This is the test I was created

```
    func Test_parseFile(t *testing.T) {

        yamlfile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./testdata/file.yaml")

        type Properties map[string]string
        type Parameters map[string]interface{}

        type Modules struct {
            Name string
            Path string `yaml:"path,omitempty"`
            Requires   []Requires `yaml:"requires,omitempty"`
            Properties Properties `yaml:"properties,omitempty"`
        }

   type Requires struct {
      Name       string     `yaml:"name,omitempty"`
      Properties Properties `yaml:"properties,omitempty"`
    }



    type args struct {
        contentFile []byte
    }


     tests := []struct {
            name        string
            args        args
            wantOut     Properties
            wantNoTests bool
            wantErr     bool
        }{
            {
                name: "test",
                args: args{
                    contentFile: yamlfile,
                },

                wantOut: Modules{
                    Name: "srv",
                    Path: "srv1",

                    Properties{
                        "LOG_LEVEL":       "info",
                        "DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL": "ALL",
                    },
                    Parameters:{
                        "mem":"12G",
                    },
                    Requires: {
                        name: "db",
                        Properties{
                            "CONFIG": '[tomcontext.xml:
                            {"service_nameDB" : "~{con-name}"}]'   
                        },
                    },
                },

                wantNoTests: true,
                wantErr:     true,
            },
        }
```

This is the assertion code

```
for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {

            gotOut := ParseFile(tt.args.contentFile)


            if !reflect.DeepEqual(gotOut.Modules[1], tt.wantOut) {

                t.Errorf("parseFile() = %v, want %v", gotOut.Modules[2], tt.wantOut)
            }
```

The error is :

```
parseFile() = map[], want map[LOG_LEVEL:info DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL:ALL]
```

How should I overcome it to check the module properties ?

The `ParseFile` method is just `err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlFile), &yamlconent)`

Comment: did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain what the question is but I managed to get your test to work like this:

```
package sandbox

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Properties map[string]string
type Parameters map[string]interface{}

type Requires struct {
    Name       string     `yaml:"name,omitempty"`
    Properties Properties `yaml:"properties,omitempty"`
}

type Module struct {
    Name       string
    Path       string     `yaml:"path,omitempty"`
    Requires   []Requires `yaml:"requires,omitempty"`
    Properties Properties `yaml:"properties,omitempty"`
    Parameters Parameters `yaml:"parameters,omitempty"`
}

type File struct {
    Modules []Module
}

func Test_ParseFile(t *testing.T) {
    input := []byte(`ID: demo
version: 0.0.5

modules:
 - name: db
   path: mtb
   requires:
    - name: vi_db


 - name: srv
   path: srv1
   properties:
     LOG_LEVEL: "info"
     DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL : ALL
   parameters:
     mem: 12G
   requires:
     - name: db
       properties:
            CONFIG: '[tomcontext.xml:
              {"service_nameDB" : "~{con-name}"}]'`)

    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        wantOut Module
    }{
        {
            name: "test",

            wantOut: Module{
                Name: "srv",
                Path: "srv1",

                Properties: Properties{
                    "LOG_LEVEL":       "info",
                    "DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL": "ALL",
                },
                Parameters: Parameters{
                    "mem": "12G",
                },
                Requires: []Requires{
                    {
                        Name: "db",
                        Properties: Properties{
                            "CONFIG": `[tomcontext.xml: {"service_nameDB" : "~{con-name}"}]`,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }

    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            actual, err := ParseFile(input)
            require.NoError(t, err)
            require.NotNil(t, actual)
            require.Len(t, actual.Modules, 2)
            assert.Equal(t, tt.wantOut, actual.Modules[1])
        })
    }
}

func ParseFile(yamlFile []byte) (File, error) {
    var f File
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &f)
    return f, err
}
```

Note that I imported https://github.com/stretchr/testify to make tests a bit easier. Of course you could replace this with your original `reflect.DeepEquals` check. Testify is useful here because it will print a   useful diff in case the expectation is not met.